# Unable to link favicon after change to JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, github, hyperlink, github-pages

On my local directory, it all works. I have a JavaScript file that creates the favicon and links style.css. In the script tag, nothing works. These are where the raw code can be found, and none of them work:

- https://rawgit.com/KnowledgeableKangaroo/KnowledgeableKangaroo.github.io/dcd2ad44389211152adad1e8f4d3009b8010a665/script.js
- https://cdn.rawgit.com/KnowledgeableKangaroo/KnowledgeableKangaroo.github.io/dcd2ad44389211152adad1e8f4d3009b8010a665/script.js
- https://rawgit.com/KnowledgeableKangaroo/KnowledgeableKangaroo.github.io/master/script.js
- https://cdn.rawgit.com/KnowledgeableKangaroo/KnowledgeableKangaroo.github.io/master/script.js

I used the 3rd one, but as soon as I made a change to script.js everything broke! Basically, in my `script.js`, I link to the favicon relative to the repository, and I link the style.css file relatively, using createElement and attributing, and append it to the head.

```
const link = top.document.createElement("link");
link.type = "image/x-icon";
link.rel = "shortcut icon";
link.href = "./icon.ico";
top.document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);

const stylesheetLink = top.document.createElement("link");
link.type = "text/css";
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.href = "./style.css";
top.document.querySelector("head").appendChild(link);

console.log("The style was linked and the favicon was added.");
```

Everything was working fine until I added the second section - linking `style.css` - and, as they were connected via branch (not recommended) the favicons went away.

Why is this happening and how do I fix this? The branch links didn't work because they are cached permanently, but what about the commit-hash links?

#### 9/19/2018

Now I am using the second link with CDN and the commit, and still the code above doesn't work. I have two other functions, `goToHomePage()` and `goBack()` which do work fine. Everything works locally, on Sublime Text 3 when I run it in an equivalent HTML file. The favicons appear. Why does it work locally but not on GitHub Pages?

#### 9/20/2018

I have added a debugging `console.log()` statement saying

> The style was linked and the favicon was added.

After updating the commit for one of my repositories and pushing, it printed! So, the facts are

- Other functions work
- Console.log statement showing up
- Before making a change to `script.js` everything was working fine.
- After making a change to `script.js` the favicons disappeared which were being linked through `script.js`
- Manually adding it by inspecting element on the webpage and adding the favicon works

I infer that the problems lies

- Not in the file's raw code because the log function worked
- With creating the link element - I kept switching between `top.document` and `document` but through the console I found they are exactly the same

Comment: Any errors reported in your JavaScript and / or Network consoles?

Comment: No, no errors. Before, it was saying 404, but that was because not all my repos had a file that I was linking to through script.js

Comment: Can you please explain what _"everything broke"_ actually means? How is it _"not working"_?

Comment: Edited my post with an MCVE and more information @Phil

Comment: You might find that it's a cache problem. Favicons are aggressively cached by your browser

Comment: Before I made the change, the favicon worked fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180394/discussion-between-marvin-and-phil).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second section - the linking of the stylesheet, the `link` variable is being appended again, when it should be the `stylesheetLink` variable being appended. On the last line of the MCVE, change `.appendChild(link)` to `.appendChild(stylesheetLink)`.

Also, you can just do `cdn.rawgit.com/KnowledgeableKangaroo/KnowledgeableKangaroo.github.io/master/script.js`. The branch works as long as you use CDN.